# Add custom captcha field to customer forgot password form

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, overrides

I need to add math captcha to forgot password form in magento. I don't want to change default magento form layout. I want to add new magento form which overrides the default form.
I have added below code in my layout file.

```
<customer_account_forgotpassword>
        <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="contacts">
            <title>Forgot Your Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
                <title>Forgot Your Password</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="forgotpassword_form" template="mathcaptcha/forgotpassword.phtml">
                <block type="mathcaptcha/index" name="ripples_mathcaptcha" as="ripples_mathcaptcha"
                template="mathcaptcha/index.phtml" />
            </block>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_forgotpassword>
```

Here, `mathcaptcha/forgotpassword.phtml` file contains my form where I have added required fields in my form. and `mathcaptcha/index.phtml` contains the captcha field. 
But I am not able to override default form. It is displaying me default form and my form both on the page.
[image]

You can see it in the screenshot.
Can anyone please help me how to override magento default forgot password form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happened because you did not override magento default block you added one more forgot password block.

To rewrite you need to call reference to the block and assign your new template.

I think this is what you need.

```
<customer_account_forgotpassword>
    ....
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="forgotPassword">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <value>mathcaptcha/forgotpassword.phtml</value>
            </action>
            <block type="mathcaptcha/index" 
                   name="ripples_mathcaptcha" 
                   as="ripples_mathcaptcha" 
                   template="mathcaptcha/index.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </reference>
    ....
</customer_account_forgotpassword>
```